# How to get the node attributes in jstree JSON data

Tags: jquery, json, jstree

I want to get the attributes of each node in my tree. After looking online, I found a way to do it but it doesn't work. The error is (at the line of attr("description") :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'obj' of undefined
```

Here is my code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var $ = jQuery;
    $('#jstree').jstree({ 'core' : {
    'data' : [
       {"id":"parent","parent":"#","text":"parent"},
       {"id":"cs","text":"Short Stay","parent":"parent","li_attr":{"label":"Short Stay","description":"example"}},
       {"id":"ls","text":"ls","parent":"parent"},{"id":"cs_1","text":"cs_1","parent":"cs"},
       {"id":"ls_1","text":"ls_1","parent":"ls"},{"id":"cs_1_1","text":"cs_1_1","parent":"cs_1"},
       {"id":"cs_1_1_1","text":"cs_1_1_1","parent":"cs_1_1"},
       {"id":"cs_1_1_2","text":"cs_1_1_2","parent":"cs_1_1"}
    ]
} })
.on("select_node.jstree",
     function(evt, data){
          $('#data').html(data.rslt.obj.attr("description"));
     }
);
  });
```

Comment: did you mean attribute values or attribute names?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You only need to get the id of selected element and then get the attribute of that element:

```
$(function () {
    $('#jstree').jstree({ 'core' : {
    'data' : [
       {"id":"parent","parent":"#","text":"parent"},
       {"id":"cs","text":"Short Stay","parent":"parent","li_attr":{"label":"Short Stay","description":"example"}},
       {"id":"ls","text":"ls","parent":"parent"},{"id":"cs_1","text":"cs_1","parent":"cs"},
       {"id":"ls_1","text":"ls_1","parent":"ls"},{"id":"cs_1_1","text":"cs_1_1","parent":"cs_1"},
       {"id":"cs_1_1_1","text":"cs_1_1_1","parent":"cs_1_1"},
       {"id":"cs_1_1_2","text":"cs_1_1_2","parent":"cs_1_1"}
    ]
} }).on("select_node.jstree",
     function(evt, data){
          var node_id   = (data.node.id); // element id
          var description = $("#"+node_id).attr("description"); // get value of element attribute
          $('#data').html(description);
     }
);
});
```

Note that not all of the element has `description` attribute.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3q9Ma/745/)